# How to delete items by _id using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem trying to delete data by providing an array of id's (got error).
I guess it has something to do with ObjectId. Could you help me fix it?

```
User.deleteMany({
  _id: { $in:     ['638207a8b9ebc3ea8f276684',
                  '63823ffe310abc61b4ee11a0',
                  '63822a71319517d196af6d59' }
})
.then(() => res.status(200).json({ success }))
.catch(error => console.error('Error deleting users'))
```

I tried to map this array to prepend every item of it with ObjectId but got ObjectId is not found.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @user20042973 'Error deleting users' in try-catch block.

Comment: Can you print the actual error so that we know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
let userIds = ['638207a8b9ebc3ea8f276684',
    '63823ffe310abc61b4ee11a0',
    '63822a71319517d196af6d59']
    let userObjectIds = userIds.map(e=>Types.ObjectId(e))
    User.deleteMany({
        _id: { $in:  userObjectIds  }
      })
      .then(() => res.status(200).json({ success }))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error deleting users'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code you pasted above is the exact code you are running, the problem is likely your input ids array syntax. It seems as though you are missing a close square bracket (`]`). Try this instead:

```
const userIds = ['638207a8b9ebc3ea8f276684', '63823ffe310abc61b4ee11a0', '63822a71319517d196af6d59']
User.deleteMany({
  _id: { $in: userIds }
})
.then(() => res.status(200).json({ success }))
.catch(error => console.error(`Error deleting users: ${error}`))
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to follow Alex's advice by mapping them to `ObjectId` types. As a side note, it's always good practice to save your input into a variable rather than hard code it. It's also helpful for debugging to log the contents of the error from your catch callback

```
console.error(`this is my error: ${error}`)
```

Hope that helps you out, happy coding :)